# What are java class attributes encapsulated as, if not specified?

Tags: java

What is `i` encapsulated as in this case:

```
public class foo{
   int i;
}
```

What is `i` encapsulated as in this case:

```
private class foo{
   int i;
}
```

Comment: @Lrr *i is protected in both cases*. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Lrrr No it isn't, it is package private (aka default) in both cases

Comment: The exact definition can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Answer (score 1):

They are `package-private`. This means they can be seen and accessed by the classes in the same package but not by subclasses outside the package. Note that `package-private` is no Java keyword, but the implicit visibility modifier, if no modifier is present.

You can find more informations [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)